# How to get all the products starting with title 'A' in Shopify

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to get all the products starting with title A or B or C in Shopify without using collection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this might be not possible.
Ideally this would work but it doesn't:

```
  {% assign my_products = collections['all'].products | where: "title.first", "A" %}
  {% for product in my_products %}
      {{ product.title }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Let me check this, I will try to modify this.